# Copying contents of downdown menu to database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, drop-down-menu

I am trying to copy the contents of a drop-down menu into a SQL database. However when I run the following code, I get the name of the drop down menu list. How do I display the values of the drop down menu? Here in the code Label4 and Label5 are the drop-down menus. 
Thanks

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=FRMDEVSQL03; Initial Catalog=VisualStudioTest;");
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO ticket(person_created, category_id, summary, ticket_status) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "',  '" + Label5.Text + "', '" + txtName0.Text + "', '" + Label4.Text + "');");
        com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO persons(LanID) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "');");
        //com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO ticket(person_created, summary) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtName0.Text + "');");
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to use `SelectedValue`, not `Text`. Also sidenote:  Your query is a prime target for SQL Injection attacks, and should be parameterized.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I am new to .NET and SQL. When I replace it it gives me this error- Error 63 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @error_404 do you mean `ToolStripMenuItem` ? What kind of drop down menu are you talking about?

Comment: @error_404 I don't see how you've turned a `Label` into a `DropDownMenu` ... can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Insertdata()
}

public void Insertdata()
{
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=FRMDEVSQL03; Initial Catalog=VisualStudioTest; User ID=Aghosh; Password=SummerClerk");
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO ticket(person_created, category_id, summary, ticket_status) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "',  '" + Label5.selectedvalue + "', '" + txtName0.Text + "', '" + Label4.selectedvalue + "');");
        com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO persons(LanID) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "');");
        //com.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO ticket(person_created, summary) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtName0.Text + "');");
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```